# new error when getting basemap from stamenmaps

Tags: r, stamen-maps

I've previously used the below code for getting a basemap from `stamenmaps`, but I tried running it today and I'm getting an error message.  If I change the zoom to a value <= 5, then it runs, but not for anything higher.

```
library(ggmap)
base <- get_stamenmap(bbox = c(left   = -70.2, 
                               bottom = 43.0,
                               right  = -49.8,
                               top    = 54.5), 
                        zoom = 8, maptype = "terrain-background", color = "color")
ℹ Map tiles by Stamen Design, under CC BY 3.0. Data by OpenStreetMap, under ODbL.
Error in f(init, x[[i]]) : 
  number of rows of matrices must match (see arg 2)
```

Comment: Not sure why you seem to think that`ggmap:get_stamenmap()` is somehow related to `rnaturalearth`, but Stamen tiles are now hosted by Stadia - https://maps.stamen.com/stadia-partnership/ , `ggmap` still points to an old address that's not available anymore. Also check ggmap note at the end of https://docs.stadiamaps.com/guides/migrating-from-stamen-map-tiles/ .  Until pull request gets reviewed/accepted by ggmap,  perhaps try installing from  github - https://github.com/stadiamaps/ggmap  (note that method names have changed too, it's now `get_stadiamap()`)

Comment: Ah, too much switching back and forth between different mapping options.
It doesn't look like there's a way anymore to pull any of these maps as StadiaMaps is not compatible with recent versions of R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I found for getting Stamen map tiles from Stadia Maps.

**1) You'll need to get an [API key](https://client.stadiamaps.com/signup/)**

**2) Then install a dev version of ggmap and update R code with new function:**

```
remove.packages("ggmap")
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("stadiamaps/ggmap")
library("ggmap")
register_stadiamaps(key = "INSERT YOUR KEY HERE")
atlCan <- get_stadiamap(bbox = c(left   = -70.2, 
                                 bottom = 43.0,
                                 right  = -49.8,
                                 top    = 54.5), 
                        zoom = 8, maptype = "stamen_terrain_background")
```

More details [here](https://docs.stadiamaps.com/guides/migrating-from-stamen-map-tiles/).

Comment: Note you can use `install.packages("remotes"); remotes::install_github(...)`, which is a little more lightweight than `devtools`