# Stamen Map mapping no longer working in R

Tags: r, mapping, ggmap, stamen-maps

The code is as follows and has previously worked

```
DEFINE THE LIMITS, ZOOM OF YOUR MAP, AND TYPE OF MAP

spillover<-get_stamenmap( bbox=c(left=-2.2, bottom=51, right=-1.3, top=51.7),  maptype="terrain-background", zoom=2)

VISUALIZE MAP
ggmap(spillover)
```

Code used to produce map however no longer works and either times out or produces a blank green map

Comment: Tiles are now hosted by Stadia, check https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues/353 and other linked issues. And https://maps.stamen.com/stadia-partnership/ and https://docs.stadiamaps.com/guides/migrating-from-stamen-map-tiles/#ggmap

Answer (score 1):

There are some major changes in map hosting: see the [NEWS file on Github](https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/blob/master/NEWS.md), which will have broken as of Oct 31: "The existing URLs are expected to be shut off after October 31, 2023."

To solve this problem as of today (6 Nov) you first have to [register](https://client.stadiamaps.com/signup/) with Stadia Maps, generate an API key, then install the *development* version of `ggmap` from GitHub (presumably it will make it to CRAN sometime soon ...)

```r
remotes::install_github("https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap")
library(ggmap)
register_stadiamaps(YOUR_STADIA_KEY, write = TRUE)
```

The required functions have also changed slightly.

```r
spillover <- get_stadiamap( bbox=c(left=-2.2, bottom=51, right=-1.3, top=51.7),  
     maptype="stamen_terrain_background", zoom=2)
ggmap(spillover)
```

... although this still produces a blank green map.  At the default zoom level (10), I do get a terrain map. At zoom = 4 there is only a tiny bit of detail left.  Maybe these tiles just don't have the resolution you want at zoom = 2?

The example from `get_stadiamap()` does work:

```r
bbox_everest <- c(left = 86.05, bottom = 27.21, right = 87.81, top = 28.76)
ggmap(get_stadiamap(bbox_everest, zoom = 9))
```

(Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77239329/new-error-when-getting-basemap-from-stamenmaps))